# JQuery addclass and Remove class applying to for each variables not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, addclass, removeclass

In my page I used jquery addclass and remove class functionality to add border for selected image. But the images are within for loop. So it is not working for me and I tried myself with various codings. But I didn't get the expected result. The coding which I used

**List of four images within for loop**

```
<div id="containerborder">
        <?php foreach ($images as $image) { ?>

        <a href="javascript:;" title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" class="colorboxs" rel="<?php echo $image['popup'];?>"onclick="document.getElementById('image').src=this.rel"> <img src="<?php echo $image['thumb']; ?>" title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" alt="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" id="<?php echo $image['popup']; ?>" onclick="swapborder(this.id);"/>
        </a>
        <?php } ?>
```

**JQuery function**

```
<script>
 $(function() { 
 $('#contianer a').click(function() { return swapborder(this); }); 
 }); 
 // 
 function swapborder(clickObject) {
 var currentId=clickObject; 
 alert(currentId);
 $('#containerborder a').each(function() { 
 if ($(this).attr('id')==currentId) { 
 $(this).addClass('active-class'); 
 } 
else { $(this).removeClass('active-class'); } 
 }); 
 return false; 
 } 
 </script>
```

It shows the ID in alert. But after that the **$('#containerborder a').each(function() {**  is not working and the border for the images are not applying. Can anyone help me to solve this issue. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean to write `var currentId = $(clickObject).attr('id')`

However it would be way easier to just do this:

```
function swapBorder(elem) {
    $("#containerborder a").removeClass('active-class');
    $(elem).addClass('active-class');
}
```

Comment: and also pass `swapborder` as the click handler instead of an anonymous function calling it.

Comment: @Musa yes that would work, but I'd be worried that the OP has other stuff in the code that he's not showing, or he won't fully grasp that.  I don't want a copy+paste answer -> "it doesn't work!" situation.

Comment: no its not working. There are no arguments in the above mentioned function. If we get the this.id as argument in the swapborder function then how it will add border to the specified for loop image

Comment: @Rithu Sorry, I forgot to write the argument for some reason.  You can also write the click binding as `$("#container a").on('click', swapBorder);`.  Then you will be able to use `swapBorder` with `this` and no arguments.

Comment: @ExplosionPills oh ok fine. I will try that coding